# angular 2 IE 11 proiblem with angular2-polyfills

Tags: angular, internet-explorer-11, polyfills

I am trying to figure out why my angular 2 app is stuck on showing Loading... when running in IE 11.

Console shows next error:

```
SCRIPT1003: Expected ':'
```

Here's a peace of minified code picture where error happens:

[image]

I find out that this code from angular2-polyfills.js file.

```
import "angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills"
```

Note: site works on Chrome and Firefox perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you running last version. If problem continue add it to your polyfills. to filter for browser that fails.

```
var ua = navigator.userAgent;
var chrome = ua.toLowerCase().indexOf('chrome');
var msie = ua.indexOf("MSIE ");
var firefox = ua.toLowerCase().indexOf('firefox')


if(msie > -1)
{
//POLYFILLS
}
```